# Is it on-topic to ask a question about command line toolkit used in development?

Tags: discussion, scope

I personally do not work with many command line toolkits; very few. [dcmtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dcmtk) is one of them.

DCMTK is popular toolkit for DICOM and widely used. Many are using this in programming as well; like executing an external process from main application and capturing the output and then updating the main application UI. Linux or Java based programmers use this more. Many medical equipment are developed using this toolkit.

Being command line toolkit, it can also be used standalone, without involvement of any programming language. Many users of this toolkit are also using it this way.

Major reasons for asking question:

1. User asks for command.
2. User knows the command but asks for parameters.
3. User knows the parameters also but those are incorrect. Command does not work as intended.
4. DICOM environment related issue. In this case [dicom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dicom) also present most of the time. Issue can be covered under DICOM tag only; toolkit tag not needed.
5. Purely DICOM related issue. This fully comes under [dicom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dicom) alone; DCMTK is not needed. User mentions it just because he is using that toolkit.

It may happen that user is actually using the tool through program - face some problem - executes same command through command prompt; problem persists - conclude that problem is with command syntax.

In this case, mentioning the development language is not needed and not useful; it is not a problem. As a part of creating MCVE, user put the minimal part that recreates an issue.

Is it on-topic to ask a question about command line toolkit used in development?

**If it is not; then [dcmtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dcmtk) does not make sense.**

Comment: Yes, but if the question is only about command line switches of some particular application within the toolkit, it should be made clear that it's within the context of a larger application. The problem being that someone may see the question is just about using a command line application and vote to close. You might also want to edit the wiki and stress how these tools are used by developers.

Comment: Being in the same boat, my solution was to refer a framework written in either PHP or Java to get the syntax correct to achieve what I wanted. I faced a similar problem when I started working with dcmtk.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/17/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/) blog, it looks such questions are on-topic.

Comment: and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366220/5779732) is also similar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, questions about it are on-topic.

*Software tools commonly used by programmers* are on topic, if you're asking about *a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

From everything you've told me, questions like that about [dcmtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dcmtk) might certainly exist.

Note that questions about general usage of such a tool will still be off-topic (in contrast to programming-related usage)

Comment: "**and** is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" why nobody read that?

Comment: There are more words in what you quoted. If you're going to quote that, include the remainder. Stopping short conveys incorrect meaning. *I don't like whites* is much different than *I don't like whites; I prefer whole eggs in my omelet.*

Comment: @KenWhite There are, but I feel that I've quoted the content applicable to this question. I could just copy-paste the whole piece, but I've provided a link for reference. If you think I represented the content badly or took things out of context, please explain.