# When is a question about a Unix command complicated enough to be a programming question?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

I often find a Stack Overflow question that's just about how to use some Unix command, like how a complicated `ls | grep | sort` is really just how to properly use a combination of the 324 `ls` command line options.

So where is the line that indicates when a question should be migrated to Unix & Linux?

Writing Awk and Perl scripts is obviously programming. But one line sed commands? Crontabs? Systemd unit files?

Comment: imho if they're writing a script, which means they're piping outputs between commands, it's on topic. Asking about a specific command, not. But lots of folks disagree on that second part :/

Comment: When it's not in the man pages or immediately Googleable?

Comment: Ask what they want to achieve instead, that usually tells you how much effort is really needed.

Comment: This is bash programming. Command lines are mean to be used as part of bash scripts. This has to stay here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/17/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363643/5779732

Comment: In the same light, most `regex` questions are just asking about how to properly use a combination of the regex rules.

Comment: Anyways, simplistic `ls | grep | sort` questions will get flogged hard at Unix & Linux.

Comment: It's Unix arcane shell magic, so everything. :p

Answer (score 17):

There's no complexity requirement. Any command that can be typed into the shell might also be incorporated into a script, and therefore, it's a programming question. Furthermore, since the command prompt is the runtime by which these scripts are executed, even features dedicated to interactive use are allowable since the tool is [a software tool commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for their programming tasks. This means we have significant overlap with Super User, Server Fault, and Unix and Linux. Askers can choose their audience, and that choice will probably result in a different emphasis on different aspects of the problems and their solutions. That's fine and not a problem.

Obviously, the normal rules about sufficient research and question quality still apply. So poorly researched questions with trivial answers can be downvoted, and others can be closed as Too Broad, Unclear, etc. if they aren't answerable.

Here are a couple more in depth discussions of the principle:

- [Discussion about software tool questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330582/1394393)
- [Relevant discussion about PowerShell being on topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350514/1394393)
- [Discussion about help phrasing around unique to programming, primarily used by programmers, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357570/1394393)

(Those are my answers, if you're wondering before you click.)

I'll also add specifically that crontab and systemd clearly fall under "tools commonly used by programmers," as it's often necessary to work with these tools to deploy a program and make it accomplish the task it was designed to do.

Comment: It's untrue that *any* command that can be interactively entered can be used in a script, or at least, only true under a limited set of conditions. History expansion is turned off by default in scripts. All extensions marked as "User Portability" in the POSIX spec (most notably aliases) are only applicable to shells intended for interactive use, and are not present, or off-by-default in noninterative mode when they *are* present, in POSIX-baseline noninteractive interpreters. Etc.

Comment: Moreover, questions about prompt colors &c. are *by their very nature* questions strictly about interactive use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy One could make the same argument about [Python's REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33683744/1394393), but these are still tools commonly used by programmers.

Comment: Python's REPL is *exclusively* used by programmers, which is what the "**unique to** software development" language at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic requires. POSIX-y interactive shells, by contrast, are widely used by operations staff and end users; they have a large non-developer audience.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, it isn't. It can be used by anyone who wants to run a quick snippet. I bet you money that data scientists fire it up to leverage numpy and pandas at times, without any intention of ever scripting the process. Furthermore, "exclusively used by programmers" is clearly not a requirement for being on topic. I edited in a sentence about it, anyway.

Comment: "Exclusively used by programmers" was my own wording, but "unique to software development" is a direct pull from an AND condition in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy By that logic, git is off-topic.

Comment: git is a tool developed with software development as its sole intended purpose and primary audience today; it's still on-topic even with the strict reading.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've discussed "unique to software development" in detail [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357570/1394393).

Comment: BTW -- I [handle a lot of bash questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/topusers) here, and the thing that gets me about `ls | grep | sort` type questions is that they're generally asked, and answers selected, without any kind of regard to either robustness in the face of unusual inputs, compliance with best practices, or other goals besides terseness. Having a bunch of acknowledged bad practice code snippets floating around in a resource also used by people (hopefully) doing serious development is harmful to the quality of the site as a whole, or at least the larger tag.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have similar complaints about Python questions. The problem is not unique to command line tools, and it's probably not unique to SO. It is a global problem with how people approach question asking and answering.

Answer (score 6):

As always, context matters. If you want to know how to start a service in a system that uses systemd, other than being already repeated through the entire internet, is not a issue that you **only have in the context of software development**. How to start a service when you install a package in your favorite distro otherwise is acceptable on SO, since it's in the context of software development, since you are crafting a package using the helper/tools given by the package manager to start the service.

In general, if you see a question about something that you expect an end user, not involved in any way in software development, to do, it's very likely that is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: that last sentence is a pretty clever way to describe our scope.

Comment: I don't expect users who know nothing about software development to be working in bash or any other command prompt. Does that mean everything about it is on topic?

Comment: @jpmc26 "only have in the **context of software development**"

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the answer claiming that any usage of a command-line shell is programming.  If interactive use of a shell is equal to (basic) scripting, then that indicates that simple scripts are not programming either, any more than a macro recording is.

Shell programming uses the programming aspects of the shell.  At least one of:

1. control flow
2. functions
3. variable expansion

Basically, the things that make bash Turing-complete.

Comment: Your answer would make [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3915075/1394393) off topic, even though it's clearly relevant to programming.

Comment: @jpmc26: That question *is* off-topic.  It also predates the sites where it would best fit today.

Answer (score -2):

Hmmm. That's actually a good question as the Unix shell was in a way designed to blur the distinction.

I recommend the following: when it's being parameterized for saving into a (potentially one-line) script. I can't comment on systemd unit files, but crontab can theoretically qualify as you have to start really thinking about failure modes and partial completion.